# start explorer with selection via Excel

Tags: excel, file, vba, select

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong in this little snippet here? :/

```
    For Each fileFullname In files
    fileFullname
    fileName = Mid$(fileFullname, InStrRev(fileFullname, "\") + 1)


    If fileName Like "*" + pattern + "*" Then
    Process.Start("Explorer", "/e,/select," & fileFullname)
```

This should work i think but i'm getting the error expected: =

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: at the end of Process.Start("Explorer", "/e,/select," & fileFullname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Call Shell("C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /Select, """ & FullFilePath & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Ok did work thanks for that, now it says that an object is required but i think that's another problem. Thanks!

Comment: i have to wait 5 Minutes but i'll do it. has the object something to do in this Process.start part?

Comment: So, when i call it like this: Call Shell("C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe", "/e,/select," & fileFullname & "", vbNormalFocus) it should work i think but i get a new problem, wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment to a

Comment: Modified it. Try again.